# Eclipse plugin scanner and partition scanner

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am making my own powershell editor plugin for eclipse. Currently the editor has a good code highlighting. But to be able to make a good outline view and formatting I need a good document partitioning. So I have created partition scanner (extends RuleBasedPartitionScanner) currently with just two rules:

```
IToken psComment = new Token(PS_COMMENT);
IToken psFunction = new Token(PS_FUNCTION);

IPredicateRule[] rules = new IPredicateRule[2];

rules[0] = new EndOfLineRule("#", psComment);
rules[1] = new SingleLineRule("function", "{", psFunction);

setPredicateRules(rules);
```

I have created it with my document using FastPartitioner with all content types required (IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE, PowershellPartitionScanner.PS_FUNCTION, PowershellPartitionScanner.PS_COMMENT)

For the highlighting I have created a scanner (extends RuleBasedScanner).

In the configuration class I've overridden the getPresentrationReconciler:

```
DefaultDamagerRepairer dr = new DefaultDamagerRepairer(
                new PowershellScanner());
reconciler.setDamager(dr, PowershellPartitionScanner.PS_FUNCTION);
reconciler.setRepairer(dr, PowershellPartitionScanner.PS_FUNCTION);
dr = new DefaultDamagerRepairer(new PowershellScanner());
reconciler.setDamager(dr, PowershellPartitionScanner.PS_COMMENT);
reconciler.setRepairer(dr, PowershellPartitionScanner.PS_COMMENT);
dr = new DefaultDamagerRepairer(new PowershellScanner());
reconciler.setDamager(dr, IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
reconciler.setRepairer(dr, IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
return reconciler;
```

I have overridden:

```
@Override
    public String[] getConfiguredContentTypes(ISourceViewer sourceViewer) {
        return new String[] { IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE,
                PowershellPartitionScanner.PS_COMMENT,
                PowershellPartitionScanner.PS_FUNCTION };
    }
```

I currently have my document nicely partitioned. BUT there is no code highlighting. Everything is black.

If I am not partitioning the document the highlighting works.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually,
this fixed my problem. In my FileDocumentProvider extension have added IDocumentExtension3. By using the it I could have both types of rules.

```
IDocument document = super.createDocument(element);
IDocumentExtension3 docExtension = (IDocumentExtension3) document;
if (document != null) {
    IDocumentPartitioner partitioner = new DebugPartitioner(Activator
            .getDefault().getPowershellPartitionScanner(),
            new String[] { IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE,
                    PowershellPartitionScanner.PS_FUNCTION,
                    PowershellPartitionScanner.PS_COMMENT });
    partitioner.connect(document);
    docExtension.setDocumentPartitioner(
            Activator.POWERSHELL_PARTITIONING, partitioner);
}
return document;
```

The solution was found in PyDev eclipse plugin.

Comment: Can you tell what is the debug partitioner and what is its role? [Why do you need the partitioner and paritition-based reconcilers](http://blog.darevay.com/2007/11/the-eclipse-reconciler/comment-page-1/#comment-33203)?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the mistake lies in defining duplicate rules for the things you want to highlight. It seems you have the rules which are defined in PowershellPartitionScanner also defined in PowershellScanner.

Do not use your PowershellScanner for highlighting those partition rules but use a separate scanner for that purpose.

**1.** First remove the duplicate rules from PowershellScanner which are already defined in PowershellPartitionScanner.

**2.** Then define a scanner for highlighting partitions (e.g. from Eclipse sample "SampleJavaEditor")

```
class SingleTokenScanner extends BufferedRuleBasedScanner {
    public SingleTokenScanner(TextAttribute attribute) {
        setDefaultReturnToken(new Token(attribute));
    }
}
```

**3.** Modify getPresentrationReconciler within your configuration class:

```
DefaultDamagerRepairer dr;

// General highlighting
dr = new DefaultDamagerRepairer(new PowershellScanner());
reconciler.setDamager(dr, IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
reconciler.setRepairer(dr, IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);

// Function partition
dr = new DefaultDamagerRepairer(
    new SingleTokenScanner(
        new TextAttribute(colorManager.getColor(new RGB(255, 0, 0)))
    )
);
reconciler.setDamager(dr, PowershellPartitionScanner.PS_FUNCTION);
reconciler.setRepairer(dr, PowershellPartitionScanner.PS_FUNCTION);

// Comment partition
dr = new DefaultDamagerRepairer(
    new SingleTokenScanner(
        new TextAttribute(colorManager.getColor(new RGB(0, 255, 0)))
    )
);
reconciler.setDamager(dr, PowershellPartitionScanner.PS_COMMENT);
reconciler.setRepairer(dr, PowershellPartitionScanner.PS_COMMENT);

return reconciler;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I also had the concern that the duplicate rules interfere, the problem is that that I have the same rules for highlighting and partitioning. My solution is above. Your comment will be highly appreciated.